# Replacing backslashes with forward slashes with str_replace() in php

Tags: php

I have the following url:

```
$str = "http://www.domain.com/data/images\flags/en.gif";
```

I'm using `str_replace` to try and replace backslashes with forward slashes:

```
$str = str_replace('/\/', '/', $str);
```

It doesn't seem to work, this is the result:

```
http://www.domain.com/data/images\flags/en.gif
```

Answer (score 124, accepted):

you have to place double-backslash

```
$str = str_replace('\\', '/', $str);
```

Comment: @Subdigger: Technically that wasn't correct, but you could have waited a little longer to let him fix the code...

Comment: @genesis your answer is the same as his.

Comment: see below _You need to escape "\" as well._

Comment: I think the syntax for `str_replace()` changed so that `$str` should now be the first argument.

Answer (score 28):

```
$str = str_replace('\\', '/', $str);
```

Comment: This answer was BEFORE accepted answer;) Should be marked as the correct one since it is the same;)

Answer (score 12):

No regex, so no need for //.

this should work:

```
$str = str_replace("\\", '/', $str);
```

You need to escape "\" as well.

Comment: @Subdigger: the posting software replaced my double slashes by one because I forgot to use a "code" block. It's pretty lame of you to downvote and then post the exact same solution.

Comment: @Sylverdrag: actually Subdigger was first poster of an answer ;)

Comment: @Genesis: Darn. Didn't see any answer when I posted, but this thing just goes so fast...

Answer (score 5):

You need to escape backslash with a \

```
  $str = str_replace ("\\", "/", $str);
```

Answer (score 2):

Single quoted php string variable works.

```
$str = 'http://www.domain.com/data/images\flags/en.gif';
$str = str_replace('\\', '/', $str);
```

Answer (score -2):

You want to replace the Backslash?

Try stripcslashes:

> http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripcslashes.php

Comment: This removes slashes, not replaces them like the question was asking for. Also, could you link to English versions of the PHP manual, please. ;)