# Replace string in php with str_replace or preg_replace

Tags: str-replace

Hello I need to find \' and replace with '.

I am trying to use this code but its not working:

```
str_replace("\'", "'", $code);
```

any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

`str_replace()` returns a new string with the replacement done, so you need to code it like this, also because the `\` backslash is the escape character you may need to escape the escape char

So either:

```
$new_str = str_replace("\'", "'", $code);
```

which works for me, or

```
$new_str = str_replace("\\'", "'", $code);
```

which also works for me

Answer (score 0):

str_replace returns a string or an array with the replaced values.
so try:

```
$newCode = str_replace("\\", "'", $code);
```

Also note the double slash to escape.

see: [Replacing backslashes with forward slashes with str_replace() in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6806597/replacing-backslashes-with-forward-slashes-with-str-replace-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

you can try putting double cote["] after backward slash[] like this

```
$str = "hello\"this is\"";
$next = str_replace("\"","'",$str);
echo $next;
```

output will be
    hello'this is'