# str_replace not working in my php string

Tags: php

I want to remove a special character from a string in my php page, for that I use str_replace() function. But it does't work for my script. The string is getting from server. I am using the following php code to replace that string.

```
$path= "catalog\/demo\/samsung_tab_1.jpg";
$newPath = str_replace("\/","/",$path);
```

But the above str_replace() function is not working properly in my script.

I want to get the output like,

**catalog/demo/samsung_tab_1.jpg**

Please help.

Comment: Kindly use `preg_replace()` . http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Comment: its giving me this `catalog/demo/samsung_tab_1.jpg` means working..

Comment: It is working for me.

Comment: Its working! Trust us. :)

Comment: duplicated of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6806597/replacing-backslashes-with-forward-slashes-with-str-replace-in-php

Comment: what is the result of `echo $newPath;` ?

Comment: @devpro catalog\/demo\/samsung_tab_1.jpg

Comment: try with // double backslashes as mentioned in answer and replace with ""

Comment: try this $result = str_replace("\\","",$path);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `\/` you can remove forward slash by using double backslashes:

```
<?php
$path= "catalog\/demo\/samsung_tab_1.jpg";
$newPath = str_replace("\\","",$path); // replace with empty string ""
echo $newPath; // catalog/demo/samsung_tab_1.jpg
?>
```

Comment: @Akhil: are u using `$path` or `$newPath` where you want to print?

Comment: @Akhil: and i hope you are using .php extension.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$path= "catalog\/demo\/samsung_tab_1.jpg";
if (preg_match('/\//', $path)){
    echo $newPath = str_replace("\/","/",$path);
}else{
    echo $newPath = $path;
}
?>
```

I hope this will work for you.