# How to replace "\" to "/" in PHP

Tags: php, str-replace

I have problem when replace char \ to / here my code:

```
$loc = str_replace('\','/',$loc);
```

but that code error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '>' in /

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6806597/replacing-backslashes-with-forward-slashes-with-str-replace-in-php

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the backslash:

```
$loc = str_replace('\\','/',$loc);
```

See also:
[Do I need to escape backslashes in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3415683/do-i-need-to-escape-backslashes-in-php)